# Adding CSS background color to a button in Javascript function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add background color to a button in a javascript function. This is my code.

```js
$('#theme').on('click', function () {
    myApp.modal({
        verticalButtons: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Themes Category',
                onClick: function() {
                        document.getElementById('content_01').style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById('content_02').style.display = "block";
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'All themes',
                onClick: function() {
                    myApp.alert('You clicked second button!')
                }
            },
        ]
    })
});
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>

<button class="col button button-fill" id="theme">Themes</button>
```

I added  `buttons.style.background = '#FF00AA';` to add background color to the button which is in the function. But it does not work. So how can I do this. Can anyone help me.

Comment: `$$('#theme').on('click', function () {` should be `$('#theme').on('click', function () {` must be a typo i think, edit the question

Comment: try `this.style.background = '#FF00AA'` inside onClick event function

Comment: You're may using your `id="theme"` more than once?

Comment: can u please show your myapp.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('#theme').on('click', function () {
    myApp.modal({
      verticalButtons: true,
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Themes Category',
        onClick: function() {
          document.getElementById('content_01').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('content_02').style.display = "block";
        },
        className: "buttonRed"
      },
      {
        text: 'All themes',
        onClick: function() {
          myApp.alert('You clicked second button!')
        },
        className: "buttonRed"
      }
    ]
  })
});
```

```css
.buttonRed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="col button button-fill" id="theme">Themes</button>
```

You need to define a class in CSS & use `className` property to add the class in button.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I want to add background color to the button which is in myApp.modal({} function. not for the "Themes" Button

Comment: @ChathuriFernando I have updated the answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.style.backgroundColor="red";` 
 
**OR** in JQuery `$(this).css("background-color","red");` 
 
See here:https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

```js
$('#theme').on('click', function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor="red";
    myApp.modal({
        verticalButtons: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Themes Category',
                onClick: function() {
                        document.getElementById('content_01').style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById('content_02').style.display = "block";
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'All themes',
                onClick: function() {
                    myApp.alert('You clicked second button!')
                }
            },
        ]
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="col button button-fill" id="theme">Themes</button>
```

Comment: I want to add background color to the button which is in myApp.modal({} function. not for the "Themes" Button

Comment: so use it inside the `onClick` function:

Comment: `onClick: function() {this.style.backgroundColor="red";
                    myApp.alert('You clicked second button!')
                }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).css('background-color','#f47121');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).css('background-color', 'red');` in JQuery

```js
$('#theme').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="col button button-fill" id="theme">Themes</button>
```

Or even `$(this).css('background', 'red')`

```js
$('#theme').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="col button button-fill" id="theme">Themes</button>
```

Comment: I want to add background color to the button which is in myApp.modal({} function. not for the "Themes" Button